# PHP foreach loop running one extra time

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a bit of trouble with this for loop here and hope to get some help !

So I will recreate a simplified version of the loop here:

```
foreach($quote as $key => $item) {
  if(isset($item['dbid'])){
    $q_sql = new mysql_builder2('quote',3);
  } else {
    $q_sql = new mysql_builder2('quote',2);
  }
  $q_sql->addArgument('name', $name);
  $q_sql->addArgument('curr', $curr);
  foreach($term[$key] as $data) {
    if(isset($data['term_id']) {
      $t_sql = new mysql_builder2('details',3);
    } else {
      $t_sql = new mysql_builder2('details',2);
    }
    $t_sql->addArgument('date', $date);
    $t_sql->addArgument('term', $termnum);
    mysqli_query($dbc, $t_sql->build());
  }
mysqli_query($dbc, $q_sql->build());
}
```

Okay, so I think I got it all right here.

---

EDIT: Before the loops I have the following :

```
$quote = $_POST['quotes'];
$term = $_POST['terms'];
```

Inside the HTML the name of these elements is structured like so:

```
quotes[1][name]
quotes[1][curr]
terms[1][1][date]
terms[1][1][termnum]
```

and then if there's a second:

```
quotes[2][name]
quotes[2][curr]
terms[2][1][date]
terms[2][1][termnum]
terms[2][2][date]
terms[2][2][termnum]
```

etc..

---

Explaination:
First, mysqli_builder2 is a premade function that creates SQL queries.. When the value is 3, it sets UPDATE, when it's 2 it does INSERT

Now, what will happen is a user will fill out a form and the data will go into two tables, Quote and Details. For each single entry into Quote, there can potentially be multiple in Details (note: I've left out a lot of fields in my example code to save space but there are links between the 2 tables).

My problem here is when I run this for a very simple UPDATE, the second foreach loops runs one extra time always, and it is always an INSERT with random values for each field.. I can't seem to figure why this is happening because it works 100% properly for the first foreach loop..

Example array output when submit:

```
Array
(
    [0] => UPDATE quote SET job_id = 2, wo_id = 9952, quote_num = '1a', revenue = '100.00', cost = '100.00', currency = 1, term = 1 WHERE id = 5857;
)
Array
(
    [0] => UPDATE details SET user_id = 532, job_id = 2, wo_id = 9952, quote_num = '1a', percent = 10, term = 1, active = 1, status = 0, date_picked = '2015-02-04', date_submitted = now() WHERE id = 588;
    [1] => INSERT INTO details(user_id, job_id, wo_id, quote_num, percent, term, active, status, date_picked, date_submitted) VALUES(532, 2, 9952, '1a', 6, 6, 1, 0, '1969-12-31', now());
)
```

This INSERT should not be there at all (notice the date going in) ..

Anyways, I'm kind of stuck here and any help is appreciated. If you need any other info just ask :)

Thanks !

Comment: what is $term[$key] in foreach loop?

Comment: I will update OP with explaination, 1 min

Comment: While you're at it, try to make it a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example , see http://sscce.org/ , (with mock a data and anyhing else you'd need to copy&paste&run it)

Comment: @VolkerK, Okay I will read that link you send me and see if I can create something like that Thanks!

Comment: The code look no problem, then problem may be the data. Have you tried dumping out $_POST just before the first loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you copy the code as is?
you have got syntax error:

```
 if(isset($data['term_id']) {
```

should be:

```
 if(isset($data['term_id'])) {
```

Comment: That's not it, I just messed that up when typing here it's good in my code